# The POST method is not supported for comment function

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm trying to make a comment function where comment will be received by the live singer. Here is the comment model

```
class Comment extends Model


public function liveSinger()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(LiveSinger::class);
}

public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id');
}
```

Here is the controller

```
public function submitComment(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the comment data
    $request->validate([
        'comment' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'liveSingerId' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $liveSinger = LiveSinger::find($request->input('liveSingerId'));

    if (!$liveSinger || $liveSinger->is_live !== LiveSinger::IS_LIVE || $liveSinger->status !== LiveSinger::IS_LIVE) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Live singer not available'], 404);
    }

    // Create a new Comment instance
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->live_singer_id = $liveSinger->id;
    $comment->sender_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $comment->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $comment->save();

    // Redirect back to the SOS screen with a success message
    return redirect()->route('sos_screen.index')->with('success', 'Comment submitted successfully');
}
```

Here is the index file

```
<div class="inner_card my-2">
        <button id="commentButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal">
           Comment
        </button>
</div>
```

Here is the modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="commentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="commentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="commentModalLabel">Add a Comment</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form data-liveSingerId="{{ $liveSinger->id }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Your Comment:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script

```
$("#commentButton").click(function() {
    $("#commentModal").modal("show");
});

$("#commentForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        var liveSingerId = $(this).data("liveSingerId");

        // Send an AJAX POST request to submit the comment
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('submit-comment')}}",
            data: {
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", // Include CSRF token
                liveSingerId: liveSingerId, // Pass the liveSingerId
                comment: formData // Include the comment data
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Close the comment modal
                $("#commentModal").modal("hide");

                // Optionally, you can display a success message
                alert("Comment submitted successfully");

                // Clear the comment textarea
                $("#comment").val("");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle errors here (e.g., display an error message)
                console.error("XHR Status: " + status);
                console.error("XHR Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
                console.error("Error Message: " + error);
            }
        });
});
```

Here is the route

```
    Route::post('/submit-comment', [SoSScreenController::class, 'submitComment'])->name('submit-comment');
```

However the when clicking on submit button, it returns
The POST method is not supported for route sos_screen. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
Is there any issues with the controller or script?

Comment: remove unnecessary code. Just the bare minimum that can be reproduced.

Comment: Your route name is ``submit-comment`` but you get an error like ``not supported for route sos_screen``? Please check in the web.php file if there is a route named sos_screen or maybe you have named the 2 routes with the same name.

Comment: You shouldnt return a redirect in your controller method, you should return a `success` or `fail` message

Comment: what is the point of using ajax if you are gonna redirect anyway?

Comment: hi, id ``commentForm`` from javascript missing in ``<form>`` element in your html code